# aura component throwing error on saving .cmp

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura

I am working on aura component which will fetch fields from custom metadata when object is selected on component, I have configured fields in custom metadata but when I am saving .cmp the its throwing below error

"Failed to save DynamicComponent.cmp: expecting a positive integer, found 'field' at column 8 of expression: record[field]: Source"

my code is below

```
<aura:component controller="ObjectAccessController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="accessibleObjects" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="selectedObject" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="limitRecords" type="Integer" />
<aura:attribute name="records" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="displayFields" type="List" default="{}" />

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />

<div>
    <lightning:select name="objectSelect" label="Select Object" aura:id="objectSelect" onchange="{!c.handleObjectChange}">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.accessibleObjects}" var="object">
            <option value="{!object}">{!object}</option>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:select>
    
    <lightning:input type="number" label="Limit Records" aura:id="limitRecords" value="{!v.limitRecords}" />
    
    <lightning:button label="Fetch Records" onclick="{!c.fetchRecords}" />
</div>

<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.records))}">
    <div>
    <ul>
       <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.displayFields}" var="field">
                    <th>{!field}</th>
                </aura:iteration>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.records}" var="record">
                <tr>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.displayFields}" var="field">
                        <td>{!record[field]}</td>
                    </aura:iteration>
                    <td><a href="{!'/' + record.Id}">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </ul>
    </div>
</aura:if></aura:component>
```

JS File

```
({
init: function(component, event, helper) {
    // Fetch accessible objects on component initialization
    var action = component.get("c.getAccessibleObjects");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.accessibleObjects", response.getReturnValue());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

handleObjectChange: function(component, event, helper) {
    // Handle selection of object
    var selectedObject = component.find("objectSelect").get("v.value");
    component.set("v.selectedObject", selectedObject);
    component.fetchRecords();
},

fetchRecords: function(component, event, helper) {
    // Fetch records based on selected object and limit
    var selectedObject = component.get("v.selectedObject");
    var limitRecords = component.get("v.limitRecords");
    
    var action = component.get("c.getRecords");
    action.setParams({
        objectName: selectedObject,
        limitRecords: limitRecords
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.records", response.getReturnValue());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
    var displayFieldsAction = component.get("c.getDisplayFields");
    displayFieldsAction.setParams({
        objectName: selectedObject
    });
    displayFieldsAction.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.displayFields", response.getReturnValue());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(displayFieldsAction);
},

editRecord: function(component, event, helper) {
    var recordId = event.getSource().get("v.value");
    var editUrl = '/' + recordId + '/e'; // Edit URL for the record
    window.open(editUrl, '_blank'); // Open edit page in a new tab/window
}
```

})

can I get help in over coming the issue here

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Visualforce, Aura doesn't allow you to access record fields dynamically. You need to convert your data into a matrix (an array of arrays) to show the data.

```
let records = component.get("v.records");
let fields = component.get("v.displayFields");
let output = records.map(
  (record) => ({
    Id: record.Id,
    values: fields.map(
      (field) => record[field]
    )
  })
);
component.set("v.tableData", output);
```

You'll want to call this function after you've gotten your response back for both the records and fields.

Given `records` as:

```
[
  { 'Field1': 'Value1', 'Field2': 'Value2', 'Field3': 'Value3' },
  { 'Field1': 'Value4', 'Field2': 'Value5', 'Field3': 'Value6' }
]
```

And `fields` as:

```
[ 'Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3' ]
```

`output` will look something like:

```
[
  { Id: '1111', values: [ 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3' ] },
  { Id: '2222', values: [ 'Value4', 'Value5', 'Value6' ] }
]
```

The markup would look like this:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.tableData}" var="record">
<tr>
    <aura:iteration items="{!record.values}" var="fieldValue">
        <td>{!fieldValue}</td>
    </aura:iteration>
    <td><a href="{!'/' + record.Id}">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: sorry to ask but how can I handle it in .cmp to show fields as columns and its data init

Comment: @Harish No worries. I've edited this to include the ability to have the record Id, since I noticed you needed that. I've also included the markup that you'd use.

Comment: should I need to make any changes to JS file? Thanks a lot for helping me out here